# Scala - Operation in case (x,y)=> x++y

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to scala. I was reading one code not able to understand . Can someone please help me to understand below code ?

```
 def intersectByKey[K: ClassTag, V: ClassTag](rdd1: RDD[(K, V)], rdd2: RDD[(K, V)]): RDD[(K, V)] = {
    rdd1.cogroup(rdd2).flatMapValues{
      case (Nil, _) => None
      case (_, Nil) => None
      case (x, y) => x++y
    }
  }
```

What does below line means ? How it will be evaluated ?

```
case (x, y) => x++y
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rdd1.cogroup(rdd2)` returns a value of type `RDD[(K, (Iterable[V], Iterable[V]))]`.
So - in `case (x, y)` both `x` and `y` are `Iterable[V]`.
`Iterable` overloads the `++` operator, with an implementation that simply means `union` - returning an iterable with all of `x`'s values followed by all of `y`'s values.

Answer (score 4):

The function `cogroup` returns a `RDD[(K, (Seq[V], Seq[W]))]`.

So the value is of type `Tuple2`. When you use `flatMapValues` it will flatmap over the values, which are of Type `Seq`. 
`++` for Seqs mean concatenating them. Resulting in a combined Seq.

`case (x, y)` means that you're using pattern matching. In your case if none of the values of your Tuple are Nil, the function will return `x ++ y`.

The advantage of using `flatMapValues` in this case is that it will flatten the result, therefore losing all the `None` values.

You can check out the documentation [here.](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.6.2/api/core/spark/PairRDDFunctions.html) Also if you're not sure what exactly Pattern matching or flatmaps are check [this for pattern matching](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/pattern-matching.html) and [this for flatmap](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/collection-scala-flatmap-examples-map-flatten)